# How to authenticate user via OIM API?

Tags: authentication, identity, identity-management, oim, identitymanager

I need to do oim user authentication from third party application. I am searching for OIM API for the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OIM the authentication is offloaded to the Application server (i.e. WebLogic) hence you will have to add a Authentication Provider which knows how to connect to the application which you want OIM to use for authentication.

https://blogs.oracle.com/ArdaEralp/entry/configure_oim_ad_ldap_authentication
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e13718/atn.htm#DEVSP220

The above links will provide a view into how you can configure a new Autentication provider for OIM and what an Authentication Provider actually means and its internals.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static final String OIM_HOSTNAME = "oim.hpt.lab";
public static final String OIM_PORT = "14000";
public static final String OIM_PROVIDER_URL = "t3://"+ OIM_HOSTNAME + ":" + OIM_PORT;
public static final String OIM_USERNAME = "tungpt";
public static final String OIM_PASSWORD = "Hpt123456";
public static final String OIM_CLIENT_HOME = "F:/designconsole11gr3/config";
public static final String AUTHWL_PATH = OIM_CLIENT_HOME + "/authwl.conf";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    OIMClient oimClient = null;
    try {
        //Set system properties required for OIMClient
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", AUTHWL_PATH);
        System.setProperty("APPSERVER_TYPE", "wls");

        // Create an instance of OIMClient with OIM environment information  
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(OIMClient.JAVA_NAMING_FACTORY_INITIAL, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        env.put(OIMClient.JAVA_NAMING_PROVIDER_URL, OIM_PROVIDER_URL);
        oimClient = new OIMClient(env);

        // Login to OIM with the approriate credentials
        System.out.println("Login by: "+ OIM_USERNAME);
        oimClient.login(OIM_USERNAME, OIM_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        System.out.println("Login Done!");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: add some explanation with your code. it help to understand this code.